# Whether the <audio> tag with playlist can be stylized?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I made an audio tag with a playlist of songs, but I have trouble figuring out how to style the audio tag.
Do any of you have pre-made styles, which I can include, or attach, I need some normal white MP3 player, like the one I'm sending in the picture.
[The MP3 player I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waaJF.png)

[My current player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmbjP.png)

Code explanation:
I made a player with a playlist, in which I can play which song I want to play, it also goes song by song automatically and when all the songs are gone it starts from the beginning.
I need to style my code.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>
        <style>
    .audioPlayer{
      display: block;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
            #playlist{
                list-style: none;
            }
            #playlist li a{
                color:black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            }
            #playlist li a:hover{
                color:grey;
            }
            #playlist li a:active{
                color: steelblue;
            }
            #playlist .current-song a{
                color:grey;
            }
        </style>
    
    
        <p>Muzika prosledjena preko <a href="ljubinko-stojanovic-smrtnik-privatna-baza-podataka.webnode.com">privatne baze podataka</a></p>
        <audio class="audioPlayer" src="" controls="" id="audioPlayer">
        Vaš čitač internet stranica ne podržava ovu radnju.
        </audio>
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li class="current-song"><a href="https://archive.org/download/crveni-telefon/Koktel%20ljubavi.mp3">Nedeljko Bajić Baja - Koktel Ljubavi</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://archive.org/download/radio_202012/Disco.mp3">Nedeljko Bajić Baja - Disko</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://archive.org/download/radio_202012/Radio.mp3">Nedeljko Bajić Baja - Radio</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://archive.org/download/crveni-telefon/Crveni%20telefon.mp3">Nedeljko Bajić Baja - Crveni telefon</a></li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ia601405.us.archive.org/16/items/audioplayer_202012/audioPlayer.js"></script>
        <script>
            // loads the audio player
            audioPlayer();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is technically correct, but a little short of detail. You need to use JS to watch some button actions and build your own player/control interface to hook your actions to. That is the default `<audio>` player you have, which will not be stylable as such, apart from dictating the controls.

You don't have to do it yourself though. You can start with something like [AmplitudeJS](https://github.com/521dimensions/amplitudejs), which will get you most of the way there. It's mainly HTML5 so styling should be easy enough.

[Here's a useful tutorial to achieve what you are trying.](https://serversideup.net/style-the-html-5-audio-element/)

Comment: As far as I understand, I need to write my own code for an MP3 player and include CSS and Javascript from your link?

Comment: You should be able to pick up and run with this, then customise the HTML to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to make your own music player interface, and controls. To do so you would need to make buttons (or any element) have the audio functions.

Comment: So I can't stylize the audio tag, so there is no possibility to change it in any way?

Comment: You can, you would just have to do a little extra work. But it is, for sure, in the realm of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, very useful!